# Do I need to backup my EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I’m using the g2.2xlarge instance type. This [pricing table](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/) shows that the instance has “60 SSD Instance Storage.” The [Best Practices for Amazon EC2](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-best-practices.html) tells us that “the data stored in instance store is deleted when you stop or terminate your instance.” However, I have stopped the instance and the data on it remained. So does that mean that the data is on EBS or… I'm relatively new to EC2 and I just want to know whether I need to back up my data.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you should.

Here's why:
The data in an instance store (i.e. your 60 SSDs) are guaranteed to persist only during the associated instance's lifetime. This means that data is guaranteed to persist over reboots, but not if you were to STOP or TERMINATE the instance. In this scenario the underlining hardware may be replaced and you might lose everything. You are also subject to disk drive fails that can corrupt your data.

You said you did not lose anything when you stopped the instance, but you could have.

Therefore, you should use EBS or S3 or something else to backup your data.

Bonus points: you cannot detach your instance storage, what can be a problem if you ever need to change your instance - which you are very likely to do at one point.

Source: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/InstanceStorage.html

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Backing-up is ALWAYS a good policy.

In the case of AWS EC2, however, you have the option to creating a snapshot. Follow This link:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EBSSnapshots.html

Answer (score -1):

Do you need to backup your instance?
In a purist sense - No, always assume your EC2 could fail at any time, so don't put anything on there you don't have elsewhere (ie. source code, data, etc)

If you stopped your instance and the data is still there, it's likely it's mounted on an EBS, not ephemeral storage.

Do you need to backup your EBS?
Depends on your requirement. EBS is distributed over an AZ which gives you pretty good durability, so just think about what's on there and how bad it would be if you lost it